# Is adding custom attributes using jquery metadata plugin cross browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine I have some make-believe markup containing a list of books with custom attributes using the [metadata plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata).

```
<div>
  Haruki Murakami
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span id="book5" data="{year: 2011}">1Q84</span></li>
    <li><span id="book7" data="{year: 1980}">Norwegian Wood</span></li>
    <li><span id="book9" data="{year: 2000}">Hard Boiled Wonderland</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is this cross browser, meaning working for all browsers (including IE6) ?
By working, I mean I don't want the attribute to disappear.

Comment: I don't think anybody can say what will work in _all_ browsers, but this should be fine for the top five or so popular ones including IE6.

Comment: Custom attributes "work", but it's usually not a good idea to use them. If you have custom data, consider using an object and referencing it by the id or other attribute value that has been standardised in HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will work, however, you should call the attribute `data-meta` or something to conform to the HTML5 spec.

Comment: and you can make it without plugins or even jquery: just  element.setAttribute('data-meta', ...); element.getAttribute('data-meta', ...) - 100% cross browser

Comment: @4esn0k jQuery can only use the DOM, so if it works in jQuery, it can work without it.